# NextAuth.js: JWT secret breaks application

Tags: jwt, next.js, strapi, next-auth

[I'm using Next.js (11.1.2) + NextAuth (4.0.0-beta.7) to signin into a Strapi API, using only Credentials provider (JWT).]

Whole auth flow is "working" with this `[...nextauth].js`:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'AppName',
      credentials: {
        email: {label: "Email", type: "text", placeholder: "daveglow@foomail.com"},
        password: {  label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const res = await fetch(process.env.CREDENTIALS_AUTH_URL, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        })
        const user = await res.json()

        if (res.ok && user) {
          return user
        }
        return null
      }
    })
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 30 days
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/signin',
    signOut: '/signin',
    error: '/signin'
  },
})
```

But few seconds after the user login, terminal shows this message and drop the session:

```
[next-auth][warn][NO_SECRET] https://next-auth.js.org/warnings#no_secret
[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR] https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error decryption operation failed {
  message: 'decryption operation failed',
  stack: 'JWEDecryptionFailed: decryption operation failed\n'
```

So, I tried to add:

```
secret: process.env.SECRET, //I've created using $ openssl rand -base64 32
```

Then I get two different messages

**Browser console**:

```
[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error
```

**VS Code Terminal**:

```
[next-auth][error][CALLBACK_CREDENTIALS_JWT_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#callback_credentials_jwt_error Signin in with credentials only supported if JWT strategy is enabled UnsupportedStrategy [UnsupportedStrategyError]: Signin in with credentials only supported if JWT strategy is enabled
```

I tried a couple different options, but It's been so confuse.
And now, I have no clue what to do. :(
Can you help me?

Comment: Do you get the problem after redeploying your application?

Comment: No, I can't deploy right now, I'm just running locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I upgraded to version 4.0.1. Fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bug introduced in beta 7 version of next-auth as discussed in https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/3216

Comment: Great! Thanks Donald

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert. But I think this is a current problem with the library NEXT auth 4.0.0

I could solve the problem using the version "next-auth": "^3.25.0".
and followed this [tutorial](https://www.gyanblog.com/javascript/next-js-strapi-authentication-credentials-jwt-next-auth/)